# An illegal memory access was encountered ||| CUDA

Tags: c++, cuda, parallel

Пишу программу, которая решает СЛАУ методом Гаусса. Решается она на процессоре и на видеокарте с целью замерить скорость вычислений. На процессоре все работает отлично. Но вот с видеокартой некоторые проблемы. Снизу в коде помечены комментарием методы, которые генерируют ошибку "an illegal memory access was encountered". Я делал все по образцу сложения векторов, по крайней мере старался. Проверил, что за грани массивов, с которыми работают функции на стороне видеокарты, ничего не заходит, вторжения в чужую память вроде как нет. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем моя проблема?

```
void FillMatrix(double **a1, double *b1, double **a2, double *b2, int n) {
    cout << "Коэффициенты и свободные члены:" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            a1[i][j] = rand() % 1000;
            a2[i][j] = a1[i][j];
            //cout << "a[" << i << "," << j << "] = " << a1[i][j] << endl;
            //cin >> a[i][j];
        }
        b1[i] = rand() % 1000;
        b2[i] = b1[i];
        //cout << "y[" << i << "] = " << b1[i] << endl;
        //cin >> b[i];
    }
}
__global__ void DirectMoveMP(double **a, double *b, int *n) {
int idx = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
double d;
if (idx < *n && idx > -1) {
    for (int j = idx + 1; j < *n; j++)
    {
        d = a[j][idx] / a[idx][idx]; // формула (1)
        for (int i = idx; i < *n; i++)
        {
            a[j][i] = a[j][i] - d * a[idx][i]; // формула (2)
        }
        b[j] = b[j] - d * b[idx]; // формула (3)
    }
}
//cudaDeviceSynchronize();
} 

__global__ void InversMoveMP(double **a, double *x, double *b, int *n) {
    //int idx = *n - threadIdx.x - 1;
    int idx = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    double d, s;
    if (idx >= 0 && idx < *n) {
        d = 0;
        for (int j = idx + 1; j < *n; j++)
        {
            s = a[idx][j] * x[j]; // формула (4)
            d = d + s; // формула (4)
        }
        x[idx] = (b[idx] - d) / a[idx][idx]; // формула (4)
    }
    //cudaDeviceSynchronize();
}

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
    int n;
    cout << "Порядок: ";
    cin >> n;
    double **a1 = new double *[n+1];
    double **a2 = new double *[n+1];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        a1[i] = new double[n+1];
        a2[i] = new double[n+1];
    }
    double *b1 = new double[n+1];
    double *b2 = new double[n+1];
    double *x1 = new double[n+1];
    double *x2 = new double[n+1];

    FillMatrix(a1, b1, a2, b2, n);

    double **dev_a2 = 0, *dev_b2 = 0, *dev_x2 = 0;
    int *dev_n = 0;
    int size = sizeof(double)*n;

    cudaSetDevice(0);
    cudaError_t cudaStatus;

    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_a2, size*n);    
    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_b2, size);
    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_x2, size);
    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_n, sizeof(int));

    cudaMemcpy(dev_a2, a2, size*n, cudaMemcpyKind::cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(dev_b2, b2, size, cudaMemcpyKind::cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(dev_n, &n, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyKind::cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    int threadsPerBlock = 1024;
    int blocksPerGrid = (n + threadsPerBlock - 1) / threadsPerBlock;

    cudaEvent_t start, stop;
    float time = 1;
    cudaEventCreate(&start);
    cudaEventCreate(&stop);
    cudaEventRecord(start, 0);
    //-------------------GPU------------------------------------
    DirectMoveMP << <blocksPerGrid, threadsPerBlock >> > (dev_a2, dev_b2, dev_n);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    InversMoveMP << <blocksPerGrid, threadsPerBlock >> > (dev_a2, dev_x2, dev_b2, dev_n);
    //----------------------------------------------------------
    cudaStatus = cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    if (cudaStatus == cudaSuccess) {
        printf("All is ok");
    }
    cudaEventRecord(stop, 0);

    cudaStatus = cudaEventElapsedTime(&time, start, stop);
    if(cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        printf("\nError 'cudaEventElapsedTime': %s\n\n",     cudaGetErrorString(cudaStatus));
    } // ТУТ ОШИБКА  an illegal memory access was encountered
    printf("Time to generate:  %3.1f ms \n\n", time);

    cudaStatus = cudaMemcpy(x2, dev_x2, size,     cudaMemcpyKind::cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);// ТУТ ОШИБКА  an illegal memory access     was encountered
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
     printf("Error'cudaMemcpy(...,cudaMemcpyKind::cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost)': %s\n\n", cudaGetErrorString(cudaStatus)); 
        }

    cudaDeviceSynchronize();


    unsigned int startCPU = clock();
    //-----------CPU-------------
    DirectMove(a1, b1, n);
    InversMove(a1, x1, b1, n);
    //---------------------------
    unsigned int stopCPU = clock();
    cout << "Время на CPU: " << (stopCPU-startCPU)/1000000.0 << " с" << endl;

    cout << "Решение системы(CPU): " << endl;
    //for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) cout << "x[" << i << "] = " << x1[i] << " " << endl;

    cout << "Решение системы(GPU): " << endl;
    //for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) cout << "x[" << i << "] = " << x2[i] << " " << endl;

    cudaFree(dev_a2);
    cudaFree(dev_b2);
    cudaFree(dev_x2);
    cudaFree(dev_n);
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: ну вы бы хоть код выровняли...

Comment: Я старался, но он каждый раз соскакивает. Извиняюсь...

Comment: что значит соскакивает?...

Comment: и у вас тут не хватает как минимум функции FillMatrix - это не является минимально воспроизводимым примером

Comment: Хм. Вроде все выровнено, разве нет?

Comment: Добавил функцию FillMatrix()

Comment: какое выравнено, если у вас в main все едет начиная с FillMatix

Comment: Сейчас, надеюсь, все нормально...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну а что вы делаете здесь?:

```cpp
cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_a2, size*n);    
cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_b2, size);
cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_x2, size);
cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_n, sizeof(int));

cudaMemcpy(dev_a2, a2, size*n, cudaMemcpyKind::cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
cudaMemcpy(dev_b2, b2, size, cudaMemcpyKind::cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
cudaMemcpy(dev_n, &n, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyKind::cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

Вы понимаете что куда копируете? Вы понимаете, что **a2** это массив указателей? Вы не можете использовать указатели на память выделенную на cpu с gpu (если только это у вас не встроенная видеокарта)

UPD чтобы исправить проблему вам нужно всего-то скопировать данные, а не укзатели на них

Comment: А как тогда мне это сделать? Статический массив?

Comment: всмысле как? Скопировать данные, а не указатели!

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно по указателю передать в cudaMemcpy двумерный массив, чтобы его потом еще и использовать в функциях DirectMoveMP и InverseMoveMP?

Comment: @НикитаСкворцов я извиняюсь, но вы с Си вообще знакомы? Вы знаете как, к примеру скопировать двумерный массив в Си?

Comment: Поэлементно....

Comment: @НикитаСкворцов это ответ уровня: очень просто. Опишите кратко алгоритм действий - не можете, то тогда вам сначала нужно подучить азы, ибо за вас, конечно, сделать задание можно, но вы то ничему от этого не научитесь..

Comment: У меня есть ответ. Просто из двумерного сделать одномерный. Это мое решение, надеюсь оно совпало с вашим. Но все таки, какое решение было у вас, хотя бы словесно?

Comment: @НикитаСкворцов а вы вообще читали мой ответ? Такое ощущение что нет... Еще раз: у вас проблема в том, что вы вместо копирования вашего двумерного массива скопировали указатели на память выделенную на cpu... Решение сдесь одно: скопировать данные, а не указатели на них. Вы, зачем-то, решили изменить структуру данных перед тем как их скопировать на gpu - так тоже можно, если у вас есть основания изменить структуру данных помимо того, что вы не знаете основ языка на котором пишите. Не знаю что вы еще хотели услышать...

Comment: Не спорю, что, возможно, не знаю основ. Но все таки я сюда пришел за ответом, как сделать это. Я сделаю статический массив, дальше что? Возьму на него указатель, что требуется для аргумента в функции? А как я буду дальше с ним работать, если не смогу обратиться к другим строкам массива? Я для этого спрашиваю и у вас, я пытаюсь выйти из этих суточных дебрей, а вы отправляете меня обратно. Зачем вы так?

Comment: @НикитаСкворцов я не пониманию: вы вообще читаете что вам пишут? Ну или хотя бы ваш вопрос вы сам то читали? Вы спросили: в чем проблема? Я вам ответил в чем - в неверном копировании и даже сказал как это исправить - скопировать данные. Какой ответ вы еще хотите? Чтобы я за вас код написал? Увы, но это не то, чем занимается данное сообщество - вам на фрианс. И при чем сдесь статический массив? Что вы несете? Я нигде про это не писал.

Comment: Я не понимаю, куда его копировать. Если в память видеокарты, то как я двумерный массив туда кину? Вы ответили для меня не понятно, я пытаюсь уточнить. Вы обвиняете меня в незнании азов... Может и я виноват в чем-то, но... Вы направили меня на правильный путь. Хотя бы так.

Comment: @НикитаСкворцов поймите наконец: из-за того что вы не знаете азов вы обречены делать глупые ошибки и задавать глупые вопросы, даже не понимая насколько они глупы!!! Вы говорите, что не понимаете как копировать двумерный массив, но уже взялись за изучение технологии cuda... Вам самому не кажется что вы бежите впереди паравоза?

Comment: К сожалению, меня заставляют это делать в ВУЗе. Я люблю Java, но мне в рамках данной дисциплины не разрешают делать это на моем языке. Поэтому я на таких костылях пытаюсь как-то выкарабкаться, чтобы это забыть. Может быть это мне когда-то понадобится, но я так не думаю.

Comment: @НикитаСкворцов ну, мне ваши проблемы не понять - я не учился в ВУЗе, я самоучка и все что я знаю - я изучил самостоятельно с ноля

Comment: Не могли бы вы мне еще раз помочь?) Как вы заметили, у меня перед отправкой функций на выполнение на видеокарте сделан таймер. И теперь после запуска программы из cudaEventElapsedTime выскакивает "device not ready". Я, надеюсь, что я правильно понимаю, что дело в синхронизации работы потока хоста и самой видеокарты. Я попробовал использовать cudaDeviceSync и cudaEventSync(stop) перед cudaEventRecord(stop, 0). Не помогает...

Comment: @НикитаСкворцов насчет этого, боюсь, я вам не помогу: я не часто программирую на `cuda` и у меня под рукой нет компа с видеокартой от nvidia - задайте другой вопрос, может кто знает в чем проблема. Скорее всего у вас проблема с неверной синхронизацией между cpu и gpu